# Am I abusing "rescue" for nil checks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I use `rescue` for everything, not just for "rescuing" exceptions. I mean, I just love the way it spares me verification and double checking data.

By example, lets say I have a model `Item` what may or may not have a `User`. Then, when I want to get the owner's name of the item I write:

```
item.user.name rescue ""
```

instead of something like

```
item.user.nil? ? "" : item.user.name
```

It makes the same think, since `nil.name` trigger an exception that I rescue with `""`, but I'm not pretty sure this is good practice. It makes what I want to, and it makes it with less code, but... I don't know, all that `rescue` words here and there makes me feel insecure.

Is it a bad practice or is it valid abusing of the `rescue` keyword?

Comment: Avdi Grimm argues that `try` is a code smell http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/06/28/do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try/ and http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/ , so it's not just that how you're doing it is bad, but that what you're trying to do is bad.

Comment: @ybakos I don't know, but we aren't [brothers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers_Grimm).

Comment: Ask yourself: Is my code going to run if I remove all the rescue clauses? If no, then you might want to re-consider what you're doing. A good rule of thumb is to use exceptions only for EXCEPTIONAL situations, situations you cannot predict. Invalid user input is something you can predict, so no use of exceptions here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are abusing rescue a bit, though in Rails, there is a specific method for these issues: `try`. [Documentation](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.0/classes/Object.html#M003403)

In your case, `item.user.try(:name)` might be a nicer approach.

Comment: Actually, because he said an `item` may or may not have a `user`, I believe he'd need `item.try(:user).try(:name)` :]

Comment: I don't believe so. If he has no item, then yes, you're correct. But, if the item may or may not have a user, that's the entire point of using `try`, to catch those situations where `item.user` returns nil instead of a `User`.

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is not really a good habit to get into. I've never really used this feature in Ruby since it feels like I'm just hiding error cases. It's also worth noting that you're rescuing any and all exceptions without specifying any type of expected error. It's just always looked like something which is going to make debugging down the road harder than it needs to be, although, like I've said, I've never bothered to use it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Like in most other languages, making the check yourself will run faster than using rescue.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your `rescue` abuse, check out the [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem. It's similiar to the `try` another posted suggested, but nicer. andand lets you say:

```
item.user.andand.name
```

The expression will be `nil` if `item.user` is `nil`.